# fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll':

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-office, visual-studio-2003, excel-interop

I am Migrating from my project which runs on VS2003 with MSOffice 2003 to VS2010 project.
My project makes use of assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll'
But I get the following Error.

```
2>ResolveAssemblyReferences:
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "Office, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Choosing "Office, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
2>InitializeBuildStatus:
2>  Touching "Debug\ACCT.unsuccessfulbuild".
2>CustomBuild:
2>  All outputs are up-to-date.
2>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'clr:oldsyntax' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
2>  stdafx.cpp
2>stdafx.cpp : fatal error C1107: could not find assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll': please specify the assembly search path using /AI or by setting the LIBPATH environment variable
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

I made sure that the assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' has been referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the old reference, and re-add the *2010* one.  They are actually different.  It's a bit of pain when upgrading office components.

Comment: Do you mean to add a new version of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll', supports for VS2010 ? But on my PC still MSOffice-2003 is only installed

Comment: Wait... I thought you upgraded office.  I should have read the question more carefully...  In any case, the interop dlls may be in a different place.  Click on the reference, right click and choose properties, note the path, and insure that the interop dll is actually there.  Otherwise, once again, remove and add the new one.

Comment: hmm... I already have tried all, checking, removing and again adding.. any other Idea to work out ?

Comment: Ahem.  Well, upon closer evaluation, it seems that VS2010 only support Office 2007 or Office 2010.  Most unfortunate.  So, you will need to either upgrade your Office or downgrade your VS to at least 2008.  You might be able to have VS2010 and VS2008 installed side by side.  This Blog has more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/04/24/vs-2010-and-tfs-with-office-2003.aspx

Comment: I have tried installing Office 2007 by keeping Office 2003 as is.(as I dont want to distrub my work environment for existing project using VS2003). So now, my machine has VS2003,VS2010,Office 2003, Office 2007, but still, I get the same error.. :(

Comment: After Installing MsOffice 2007, I referred using "Add Reference", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ver12.0.0.0 but no progress. I tried with ver14.0.0.0 also. Can anyone look into this issue please.